# Checking connectedness by an associated graph

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space with an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ such that each $U_\alpha$ is connected and nonempty. Form a graph as follows: for each $\alpha$ put a vertex $v_\alpha$. Also $v_\alpha$ and $v_\beta$ is connected by an edge if and only if $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ is nonempty. Let $G$ be this associated graph. Is it true that $X$ is connected if and only if $G$ is a connected graph?

I see that  if $G$ is not connected then so is $X$. But I can't show the converse.

Here is the similar question [A topological space is path connected if and only if the associated graph is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107772/a-topological-space-is-path-connected-if-and-only-if-the-associated-graph-is-con), considering path-connectedness instead of connectedness, but I can't get any help from it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is not connected, that is $X = A\cup B$ where both $A,B$ are open, non-empty and disjoint. That for each $\alpha$ either $U_\alpha\subset A$ or $U_\alpha\subset B$, coz otherwise $U_\alpha = (U_\alpha\cap A)\cup (U_\alpha \cap B)$, which makes $U_\alpha$ not connected. That contradicts existence of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $G$ connects $\alpha$ and $\beta$, while $U_\alpha\subset A$ and $U_\beta \subset B$. I'm bad at set theory, so I hope no fancy induction is needed for the last step.